# Permutations with sub permutations

Tags: probability, permutations

> Five friends - Mary, Hannah, John, Tim and Charles - are attending a
>   soccer game and are going to sit in a row with 5 consecutive seats.
>   Supposing that they sat in a random order, what is the probability of
>   John, Charles and Tim sitting together with Hannah between them?

I did:

- Total permutations = 5!
- Permutations of John, Charles and Tim with Hannah sitting between =
  $3*3*2=18$
- Now I multiply by two, because Mary can sit either on the 1st or last seat $18*2 = 36$
- Probability = $$\frac{36}{5!} = \frac{3}{10}$$

But my book says this is wrong, and the solution should be either:

> (a) $\frac{1}{5}$ $$\\$$  (b) $\frac{1}{10}$ $$\\$$  (c) $\frac{1}{20}$ $$\\$$  (d) $\frac{1}{3}$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What does it mean to say that J,C,T sit together with H in between them?  Can you show us an acceptable arrangement?

Comment: @lulu I guess it means that in the 4 seats used by J,C,T and H, Hannah sits either on the 2nd or on the 3nd seat, right?

Comment: @lulu an example of such arrangement would be JCAT, or JACT

Comment: I have no idea, it's your question.  But that seems like a strange interpretation...Why wouldn't $MJCHT$ work?

Comment: Who is A?  And that's only four letters.

Comment: It just seems like an odd phrasing.  "together" to me means that nobody is sitting between them.  Anyway, are you saying "H has at least one boy to her left and at least one boy to her right?"

Comment: @lulu When I said A I meant H, my mistake

Comment: @lulu I thought it would be easier to split the problem in sub-permutations, if you can call them that, and then add all permutations in the end.

Comment: Trusting that this is what you mean:  There are $6$ ways to permute the boys.  then $2$ slots for H to occupy, then $5$ slots for $M$ to occupy, and $6\times 2\times 5= 60$.  So I get $\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu It is a rather odd phrasing indeed, but that's just how the problem is written, I copied it straight from my book. And yes, I suppose it means that  she has one boy on both sides

Comment: In my experience, it's often the case that the difficulty of problems like these comes from bad phrasing.  Here, no statement is made about where M is sitting, so I assume she can sit anywhere.  Maybe we're meant to guess that M can only sit in the first or fifth seat, but really that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation fo the question

> what is the probability of John, Charles and Tim sitting together with Hannah between them?

is that the valid groups are these composed of these four people in contact with the condition that Hannah is not on any of the extremes.

Then the group of three men have $3!=6$ different permutations. Each one is multiplied by $2$ because Hannah can sit in second or third place for a total of $6\cdot 2=12$.

Now the last person, Mary, only can sit in one of the extremes, so the total valid permutations are $12\cdot 2=24$, and all possible permutations are $5!=120$.

Then the probability would be $\frac{24}{120}=\frac15=20\%$.

---

This step

> - Permutations of John, Charles and Tim with Hannah sitting between = $3∗3∗2=18$

was wrong. Alternatively to what I did above you can accomplish this calculus counting all the permutations between these $4$, that is $4!=24$, and after subtracting the permutations where Hannah is in one extreme, that is $2\cdot 3!=12$ for a total of $24-12=12$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks